# can't connect to server via Jsch using maven

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, private-key

I can't connect to my server via Jsch. I'm getting

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail

pom looks like that

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.53</version>
    </dependency>
```

my Code looks like that

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class UserAuthPubKey {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            String user = "....";
            String host = "....";
            String privateKey = "C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rs_user";

            jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);

            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);

            session.connect();
            System.out.println("session connected.....");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

> I had to replace the JRE - java unlimited strength policy. That solved
>   my problem